# logging ServerRequest in case of issue with Input JSON request

Tags: spring-webflux, flux

1. If the input json request is in compatible with Myprivate.class no issues.
2. Suppose in case input json request is not in compatible with Myprivate.class -> I want to print the ServerRequest. Following is the way I'm trying but it is logging and not throwing any error also. Can someone help me here.

[image]